# Best practice for appending child text in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, appendchild

Here i create a span element for an icon and then add a class to hide it (until hovered). I do the same for a second span that will hold a tooltip and adds CSS to style it.

I then loop through `shipCell` which is a column of cells, and append the `btnSpan` and the `tipSpan`. while adding the icon (a clipboard) using `.inerHTML` and adding the text "Copy ShipID" to the `tipSpan` using `.innerText`.

```
var btnSpan = document.createElement("span");
    btnSpan.classList.add('quickLink');  // Add class to all quickLinks
var tipSpan = document.createElement("span");
    tipSpan.classList.add('tooltip');    // Add class to all tooltips

for(var i=0;i<shipCell.length;i++){
        btnSpan.innerHTML = '&#128203;';
        shipCell[i].appendChild(btnSpan.cloneNode(true));  //add button to each cell

        tipSpan.classList.add('copytip');  //add class for copy buttons specifically
        tipSpan.innerText = 'Copy ShipID';
        shipCell[i].appendChild(tipSpan.cloneNode(true));  //add tool tip to each cell");
    };
```

This all works as it should (especially after learning of `cloneNode(true)` which allows it to be appended to every cell rather than just the first.

My question here is would it be a smarter move to create text nodes for the things I used `.innerHTML` on? If so, how? Because i tried creating a text node and appending it in the loop but it would add a new copy EVERY time, so the second cells tooltip said "Copy ShipIDCopy ShipID" (yes, twice)

Answer (score 0):

Well, while your existing code is not incorrect, most code in the for loop is unnecessary and can be cut down to:

```
var btnSpan = document.createElement("span");
btnSpan.classList.add('quickLink');  // Add class to all quickLinks
btnSpan.innerHTML = '&#128203;';     // Moved this out from loop

var tipSpan = document.createElement("span");
tipSpan.classList.add('tooltip');    // Add class to all tooltips
tipSpan.innerText = 'Copy ShipID';   // Moved this out from loop

for (var i = 0; i < shipCell.length; i++){
    shipCell[i].appendChild(btnSpan.cloneNode(true));  //add button to each cell
    shipCell[i].appendChild(tipSpan.cloneNode(true));  //add tool tip to each cell");
};
```

Because by using [`.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), you are also cloning all its child nodes inside. Meaning, you don't have to keep assigning `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` because by using `true` in `.cloneNode()`, they will be cloned too.

You will only need to reassign them IF you use `.cloneNode()`, without `true` argument. However, in that case, your existing code will need some minor tweaking.

```
var btnSpan = document.createElement("span");
btnSpan.classList.add('quickLink');  // Add class to all quickLinks

var tipSpan = document.createElement("span");
tipSpan.classList.add('tooltip');    // Add class to all tooltips

var btnSpanClone,
    tipSpanClone;

for (var i = 0; i < shipCell.length; i++){
    btnSpanClone = btnSpan.cloneNode();  // New btnSpan element without childNodes
    tipSpanClone = tipSpan.cloneNode();  // New tipSpan element without childNodes

    btnSpanClone.innerHTML = '&#128203;';
    tipSpanClone.innerText = 'Copy ShipID';

    shipCell[i].appendChild(btnSpanClone);
    shipCell[i].appendChild(tipSpanClone);
};
```

As for your question of whether it is smarter to use `.createTextNode()`, it makes no difference in this specific case because there is nothing else to be added to your `btnSpan` and `tipSpan`. If there is, then it MIGHT be better to use it for better code organisation and readability.

The most important thing is to make your code easily understood by anyone.

So if you think using `.createTextNode()` can make the code more readable and easier to understand, then use it. If not, then don't.

If you are talking about code performance here, you can compare both implementation yourself using [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) or some other JS benchmark tools. Most likely, the performance difference will be very tiny and can be ignored.